# Vert.x JOOQ RxJava Postgres sequential database calls

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, rx-java2, vert.x, jooq

I'm using Vert.x and JOOQ with the rx-async option:
https://github.com/jklingsporn/vertx-jooq/tree/master/vertx-jooq-rx-async

I have an HTTP verticle that routes /jooqtest to jooqRxAsyncHandler written in Kotlin:

```
private fun jooqRxAsyncHandler(context: RoutingContext) {
    val jooqConfig: Configuration = DefaultConfiguration().set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
    val dbCredentials = JsonObject()
        .put("host", "localhost")
        .put("username", "username")
        .put("password", "password")
        .put("database", "dbname")

    dbClient = PostgreSQLClient.createNonShared(vertx, dbCredentials)

    val dao = UserDao(jooqConfig, dbClient)
    println("getting. client: " + dbClient)

    dao.deleteByCondition(USER.EMAIL.eq("f@g.com"))
        .concatWith(
            dao.insert(User("f@g.com",
                "f@g.com",
                "accessToken",
                OffsetDateTime.now(),
                "f@g.com"))
        )
        .subscribe()

    dao.findOneByCondition(USER.EMAIL.eq("test@test.com.zz"))
        .doOnEvent { something, x ->
            if (x == null) {
                context.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("JOOQ test $something")

            } else {
                System.err.println("Something failed badly: " + x.message)
                context.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("JOOQ error")
            }
        }
        .subscribe()

    println("done")
}
```

Two questions:
1) Does this fire sequentially or in parallel, and how would I get everything to fire sequentially (delete, insert, select)?

2) Will this block the main thread when the .subscribe() call is made?

Answer (score 1):

Answer with some help from Clement Escoffier:

1) The two .subscribe() calls fire concurrently. The delete and insert calls combined with .concatWith() fire sequentially.

2) This is non-blocking.

Also, to run delete, insert and findByOne calls sequentially, use .ignoreElement() and .andThen() as in the following:

```
private fun jooqRxAsyncHandler(context: RoutingContext) {
    val jooqConfig: Configuration = DefaultConfiguration().set(SQLDialect.POSTGRES)
    val dbCredentials = JsonObject()
        .put("host", "localhost")
        .put("username", "username")
        .put("password", "password")
        .put("database", "dbname")

    dbClient = PostgreSQLClient.createNonShared(vertx, com.datadeploytool.database.dbCredentials)

    val dao = UserDao(jooqConfig, dbClient)
    println("getting. client: $dbClient")

    dao.deleteByCondition(USER.EMAIL.eq("f@g.com")).ignoreElement()
        .andThen(
            dao.insert(User("f@g.com",
                "f@g.com",
                "accessToken",
                OffsetDateTime.now(),
                "f@g.com"))
        ).ignoreElement()
        .andThen(
            dao.findOneByCondition(USER.EMAIL.eq("test@test.com.zz"))
        )
        .doOnEvent { something, x ->
            if (x == null) {
                context.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("JOOQ test $something")

            } else {
                System.err.println("Something failed badly: " + x.message)
                context.response().putHeader("content-type", "text/html").end("JOOQ error")
            }
        }
        .subscribe()

    println("done")
}
```